# Length of LOB data (2135980) to be replicated exceeds configured maximum 65536

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, transactional-replication

I am getting the replication error 'Length of LOB data (2135980) to be replicated exceeds configured maximum 65536'.

sp_configure was previously applied to set it to max value (-1) and a query on sys.configurations confirms that the max value (-1) is in use.

```
EXEC sp_configure 'max text repl size', -1 ; 
RECONFIGURE; 
GO

select * from sys.configurations
where name like 'max text repl size%';
GO
```

I have tried using a large value for 'max text repl size' rather than max value and turning it off and on again, to no avail.

Is there something else that may be overriding the 'max text repl size' setting or anywhere else I can look?

Comment: And you're definitely performing the reconfigure on the correct SQL Server instance?  Sorry for the stupid question!

Comment: Yes, tried RECONFIGURE, as well as RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE and this is the same instance that the error is occurring on. This is the only instance that is having this issue. No questions are stupid ;-)

Comment: Not sure if relevant but did you do it on publisher, distributor and subscriber or just publisher?

Comment: Publisher and distributor are on the same instance - this is where the 'max text repl size' setting was applied.

Comment: have you tried `EXEC sys.sp_configure 'max text repl size', 2147483647;` ?

Comment: Yes, using the max value (2147483647) was tried too.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This configuration can be changed using Management Studio by right-clicking the server -> Properties -> Advanced tab -> Miscellaneous -> Max Text Replication Size.
Or you may want to try :

```
EXEC sys.sp_configure N'max text repl size (B)', N'-1'
GO
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE
GO
```

Comment: The gotcha with this issue was that the sp_configure also needed to executed on the subscriber as well (it had already been executed elsewhere) because this was where the error was originating.